# Ticks not woking in google line chart

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization

I am using google line chart to display data in my angular app, i have labels in string form and i want to add custom labels, so i have add ticks to hAxis.

This is how i have data `['10 AM', 10], ['11 AM', 51], ['12 AM', 14.5], ['01 PM', 100]`

This is how i am adding ticks `ticks: [{v: 10, f:'10 AM'}],`

but its not displaying labels from ticks array.

I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: `ticks` should be under either `hAxis` or `vAxis`...

Comment: yes you are right, its under hAxis